# Spring Integration querying multiple api's and aggregating the response

Tags: spring-integration

I'm a newbie to Spring Integration and am looking for a few pointers regarding how I could use it as follows:

Let's say I get a request from a client which for example is looking for a price comparison for some widget. On receipt of this request I would like to call out to multiple different company api's to get different prices and aggregate the each response (different response formats) before returning to the client.

I was just wondering which patterns I could use to do this

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your requirements are fully covered with the [Scatter-Gather](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/BroadcastAggregate.html) pattern.

Spring Integration provides a particular [implementation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#scatter-gather) for you:

> It is a compound endpoint, where the goal is to send a message to the recipients and aggregate the results. Quoting the EIP Book, it is a component for scenarios like best quote, when we need to request information from several suppliers and decide which one provides us with the best term for the requested item.

Comment: Yes this looks like the pattern I need. Thank you.